# pandas simple pairwise occurrence

Tags: python, pandas

There is a function `corr` in pandas to create a table with mutual correlation coefficients in presence of sparse data. But how to calculate the number of mutual occurrences in the data instead of correlation coefficient?

i.e.

```
A = [NaN, NaN, 3]

B = [NaN, NaN, 8]

F(A,B) = 1

A = [1, NaN, NaN]

B = [NaN, NaN, 8]

F(A,B) = 0
```

I need `pandas.DataFrame([A,B]).<function>()` -> matrix of occurrences

Answer (score 0):

In pandas, you may want to use dropna: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

You can do something like

```
co_occur = df.dropna(how = "any")
the_count = co_occur.shape[0] # number of remaining rows
```

This will drop all rows where there is any NaN (thereby leaving you only with rows that contain values for every variable) and then count the number of remaining rows.

Alternatively, you could do it with lists (as in your code above) assuming the lists are the same length:

```
A = [NaN, NaN, 3]
B = [NaN, NaN, 8]

co_occur = len( [i for i in range(len(A)) if A[i] and B[i]] )
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using `numpy`

```
sum(np.sum(~np.isnan(np.array([A,B])),0)==2)
Out[335]: 1
```

For you second case

```
sum(np.sum(~np.isnan(np.array([A,B])),0)==2)
Out[337]: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

With pandas

```
(df.A.notnull() & df.B.notnull()).sum()
```

Or

```
df.notnull().all(axis=1).sum()
```